# How to remove duplicate XML nodes using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I've got an extremely long XML file, like

```
<Root>
   <ele1>
      <child1>context1</child1>
      <child2>test1</child2>
      <child1>context1</child1>
   </ele1>

   <ele2>
      <child1>context2</child1>
      <child2>test2</child2>
      <child1>context2</child1>
   </ele2>
   <ele3>...........<elen>
</Root>
```

Now I want to remove all the second `<child1>` in each `<ele>` using xslt, is it possible?
The result would be like this:

```
<Root>
   <ele1>
      <child1>context1</child1>
      <child2>test1</child2>
   </ele1>

   <ele2>
      <child1>context2</child1>
      <child2>test2</child2>
   </ele2>
       <ele3>...........<elen>
</Root>
```

Thank u, BR

Allen

Answer (score 4):

**This question requires a little bit more detailed answer** than just pointing to a good [**Muenchian Grouping**](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N4486.html#d6060e85) source.

The reason is that **the needed grouping requires to identify both the names of all children of an "ele[SomeString]" element and their parent**. [**Such grouping**](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N4486.html#d6060e238) requires to define a key that is uniquely defined by both unique sources, usually via concatenation.

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kElByName" match="*"
      use="concat(generate-id(..), '+',name())"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'ele')]">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select=
         "*[generate-id()
           =
            generate-id(key('kElByName',
                        concat(generate-id(..), '+',name())
                        )[1])
            ]"
         />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<Root>
    <ele1>
        <child1>context1</child1>
        <child2>test1</child2>
        <child1>context1</child1>
    </ele1>
    <ele2>
        <child1>context2</child1>
        <child2>test2</child2>
        <child1>context2</child1>
    </ele2>
    <ele3>
        <child2>context2</child2>
        <child2>test2</child2>
        <child1>context1</child1>
    </ele3>
</Root>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
<Root>
    <ele1>
        <child1>context1</child1>
        <child2>test1</child2>
    </ele1>
    <ele2>
        <child1>context2</child1>
        <child2>test2</child2>
    </ele2>
    <ele3>
        <child2>context2</child2>
        <child1>context1</child1>
    </ele3>
</Root>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the OP's provided XML is representative of his/her question (and the *2nd* `<child1>` inside each `<ele*>` element should be removed), then Muenchian Grouping isn't necessary:

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity Template: copies everything as-is -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Remove the 2nd <child1> element from each <ele*> element -->
  <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'ele')]/child1[2]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When run against the provided XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
  <ele1>
    <child1>context1</child1>
    <child2>test1</child2>
    <child1>context1</child1>
  </ele1>
  <ele2>
    <child1>context2</child1>
    <child2>test2</child2>
    <child1>context2</child1>
  </ele2>
</Root>
```

**...the desired result is produced:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
  <ele1>
    <child1>context1</child1>
    <child2>test1</child2>
  </ele1>
  <ele2>
    <child1>context2</child1>
    <child2>test2</child2>
  </ele2>
</Root>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your xml and question are kind of unclear, but what you're looking for is commonly called the [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) method - it's another way of asking for distinct nodes. With the appropriate keys this can be done very efficiently.

Comment: This is more of a hint than an answer. People need serious and responsible responses.

Comment: @annakata This question is on the search results, with ~14k views. I recommend cleaning up the uncivil comments here.