# How to remove duplicate xml-nodes using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to remove duplicates when all variables are exact matches using xslt.

In this xml node 3 should be removed because it is a perfect copy of node 1.

```
<root> 
    <trips> 
      <trip> 
        <got_car>0</got_car> 
        <from>Stockholm, Sweden</from> 
        <to>Gothenburg, Sweden</to> 
        <when_iso>2010-12-06 00:00</when_iso> 
      </trip>
      <trip> 
        <got_car>0</got_car> 
        <from>Stockholm, Sweden</from> 
        <to>New york, USA</to> 
        <when_iso>2010-12-06 00:00</when_iso> 
      </trip>
      <trip> 
        <got_car>0</got_car> 
        <from>Stockholm, Sweden</from> 
        <to>Gothenburg, Sweden</to> 
        <when_iso>2010-12-06 00:00</when_iso> 
      </trip>
      <trip> 
        <got_car>1</got_car> 
        <from>Test, Duncan, NM 85534, USA</from> 
        <to>Test, Duncan, NM 85534, USA</to> 
        <when_iso>2010-12-06 00:00</when_iso> 
      </trip> 
    <trips> 
<root>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicate XML nodes using XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355691/how-to-remove-duplicate-xml-nodes-using-xslt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="trip-tth" match="/root/trips/trip" use="concat(got_car, '+', from, '+', to, '+', when_iso)"/>

<xsl:template match="root/trips">   
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="trip[generate-id(.) = generate-id( key ('trip-tth', concat(got_car, '+', from, '+', to, '+', when_iso) ) )]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="trip">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Will do the trick.

It utilizes the fact that generate-id() applied to a key will take the id of the first node, that matches a given criteria. And in our case criteria is concatenated value of each trip child element.

Comment: @Flack: Generally your answer isn't entirely correct. Whenever using concatenation as key, it is safe and necessary to include in this concatenation separating strings, in order to avoid considering `concat('A','BC')` and `concat('AB','C')` to be the "same".

Comment: Actually, could you explain how I put the new data in a for-each-array?

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev, thanks for useful remark. I've edited my response for future readers.

Comment: @Kristoffer Nolgren, if I got your point right, you want to use for-each instead of apply-templates? Well, xpath expression will be the same.

Comment: @Flack: This answer has value because of the key concatenation (once it follows @Dimitre remarks...), but the rest of the stylesheet has many faults: absolute path for key/@match pattern, loosing the `root` element, push style template applying for later explicit `xsl:copy`...

Comment: @Alejandro, it's a faulty one. Though it was my first answer here and things got better.

Answer (score 2):

With a better desing, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kTripByContent" match="trip"
             use="concat(got_car,'+',from,'+',to,'+',when_iso)"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="trip[generate-id() !=
                              generate-id(key('kTripByContent',
                                              concat(got_car,'+',
                                                     from,'+',
                                                     to,'+',
                                                     when_iso))[1])]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<root>
    <trips>
        <trip>
            <got_car>0</got_car>
            <from>Stockholm, Sweden</from>
            <to>Gothenburg, Sweden</to>
            <when_iso>2010-12-06 00:00</when_iso>
        </trip>
        <trip>
            <got_car>0</got_car>
            <from>Stockholm, Sweden</from>
            <to>New york, USA</to>
            <when_iso>2010-12-06 00:00</when_iso>
        </trip>
        <trip>
            <got_car>1</got_car>
            <from>Test, Duncan, NM 85534, USA</from>
            <to>Test, Duncan, NM 85534, USA</to>
            <when_iso>2010-12-06 00:00</when_iso>
        </trip>
    </trips>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XSLT 1.0, this answer may help:
[How to remove duplicate XML nodes using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355691/how-to-remove-duplicate-xml-nodes-using-xslt). It is easier with XSLT 2.0 but that is not universally deployed