# Remove Duplicated Tag and it's childs in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, duplicates, nodes

So, I want to remove from my xml all duplicated tag and its child if exists. This example from here [How to remove duplicate xml-nodes using xslt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361445/how-to-remove-duplicate-xml-nodes-using-xslt)
it's almost the same of my problem, except the solution it's not working for me and I'm not figuring out why.

Example: the xml looks like:

```
<root>
       <row>
            <title>The Oscars Opening Ceremony: Live from the Red Carpet</title>  <!-- here -->
            <actors>Margot Robbie</actors>
            <actors>Kumail Nanjiani</actors>
            <actors>Timothée Chalamet</actors>
            <actors>Matthew McConaughey</actors>
            <actors>Nicole Kidman</actors>
            <actors>Saoirse Ronan</actors>
            <actors>Jennifer Garner</actors>
            <actors>Armie Hammer</actors>
            <actors>Sandra Bullock</actors>
            <actors>Gary Oldman</actors>
            <actors>Mira Sorvino</actors>
            <actors>Salma Hayek</actors>
            <actors>Mahershala Ali</actors>
            <actors>Jordan Peele</actors>
            <actors>Wendi McLendon-Covey</actors>
            <description>The Oscars Opening</description>
        </row>
       <row>
            <title>Tabaluga tivi</title>
            <actors>Ben Bledsoe</actors>
            <actors>Philipp Wimmer</actors>
            <actors>Patrick King Jr.</actors>
            <description>Tabaluga tivi</description>
        </row>
        <row>
            <title>Library of God</title>
            <actors>Peter Førde</actors>
            <actors>Lasse Vermeli</actors>
            <actors>Hilde Amundsen</actors>
            <description>Library of God</description>
        </row>
        <row>
            <title>The Oscars Opening Ceremony: Live From The Red Carpet</title> <!-- here again -->
            <actors>Mel Gibson</actors>
            <actors>Dwayne Johnson</actors>
            <actors>Nicole Kidman</actors>
            <actors>Robin Roberts</actors>
            <actors>Meryl Streep</actors>
            <actors>Justin Timberlake</actors>
            <description>Interviews with nominees, presenters and performers arriving for the awards ceremony; hosts Robin Roberts, Michael Strahan and Lara Spencer.</description>
        </row>
</root>
```

Desirable output result:

```
<root>
        <row>
            <title>The Oscars Opening Ceremony: Live from the Red Carpet</title>  <!-- only this one at result -->
            <actors>Margot Robbie</actors>
            <actors>Kumail Nanjiani</actors>
            <actors>Timothée Chalamet</actors>
            <actors>Matthew McConaughey</actors>
            <actors>Nicole Kidman</actors>
            <actors>Saoirse Ronan</actors>
            <actors>Jennifer Garner</actors>
            <actors>Armie Hammer</actors>
            <actors>Sandra Bullock</actors>
            <actors>Gary Oldman</actors>
            <actors>Mira Sorvino</actors>
            <actors>Salma Hayek</actors>
            <actors>Mahershala Ali</actors>
            <actors>Jordan Peele</actors>
            <actors>Wendi McLendon-Covey</actors>
            <description>The Oscars Opening</description>
        </row>
       <row>
            <title>Tabaluga tivi</title>
            <actors>Ben Bledsoe</actors>
            <actors>Philipp Wimmer</actors>
            <actors>Patrick King Jr.</actors>
            <description>Tabaluga tivi</description>
        </row>
        <row>
            <title>Library of God</title>
            <actors>Peter Førde</actors>
            <actors>Lasse Vermeli</actors>
            <actors>Hilde Amundsen</actors>
            <description>Library of God</description>
        </row>
   </root>
```

This is the xslt I'm using:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kTitleByContent" match="row"
             use="concat(title, '+', actors, '+', description)"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="row[generate-id() !=
                              generate-id(key('kTitleByContent',
                                              concat(title,'+',
                                                     actors,'+',
                                                     description))[1])]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Why is not removing duplicated ? Appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: Only use `title` for the key perhaps? It is not clear what you expect to achieve with the concatenated key value where you seem to have multiple `actors` elements in different order.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I want to remove a <row> and it's child, every time I found duplicated values for <title>. The whole XML must have only unique <row><title>...

Comment: The you simply want `use="title"` in the key declaration, Note however, that for your sample, the titles are not duplicates in terms of pure, case-insensitive string comparison as one has `Live from the Red` and the other `Live from The Red`. So you need to additionally use lower-case in XSLT 2 and later or write a long `translate` call converting all letters to lower case in XSLT 1.

Answer (score 0):

A key simply using the `title` element should do if the `title` is all you want to compare and they are exactly equal:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    
  <xsl:key name="kRowByTitle" 
           match="row"
           use="title"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="row[generate-id() != generate-id(key('kRowByTitle', title)[1])]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that however in your posted sample you have differences in the case of letters in the first and fourth `title` so you additionally might need to use the `lower-case` function in XSLT 2 and later or you need to declare two parameters with all letters you need to handle in upper-case and lower-case and use `translate`.

In XSLT 3 it would simply be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">
    
  <xsl:key name="kRowByTitle" 
           match="row"
           use="lower-case(title)"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="row[not(. is key('kRowByTitle', lower-case(title))[1])]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hey @MartinHonnen thank for your answer ! I tried here and happened exactly what you've said. Your first answer removed exactly titles but don't deal with lower or upper case in the title. Your second answer, which is exactly what I need, it's not working for me. I'm getting this error: sintaxe error on'row[not(. is key('kRowByTitle', lower-case(title))[1])]'.' You know what could be wrong?

Comment: @GuilhermeSchults, the second sample is XSLT 2/3 supported only by XSLT 2 or 3 processor like Saxon 9 or 10 or Saxon-JS 2 or Saxon-C or XmlPrime or Altova XMLSpy/Raptor. I didn't update the first sample using XSLT 1 as there is no lower-case function in XPath/XSLT 1 and you would need to store the letters you expect in two variables with one being a sequence of all upper case letters and the second a sequence of all lower-case letters and then to use the `translate` function everywhere to convert to lower case for comparison.

Comment: So basically updating the XSLT 1 sample requires a change in the XSLT structure as you can use variables in the `match` patterns in XSLT 1. Perhaps someone else is willing to spell that out.