# How to remove duplicates from xml using xsl

Tags: xslt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove duplicate XML nodes using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355691/how-to-remove-duplicate-xml-nodes-using-xslt)

I have an input in the following format.i would like to delete the duplicate elements from it

```
<pasabm:TransactionProductVO>
   <pasabm:ItemNumber>100-0711-1</pasabm:ItemNumber>
   <pasabm:ItemSource>EBIZ_01</pasabm:ItemSource>
   <pasabm:ItemUom>Ea</pasabm:ItemUom>
   <pasabm:LotNumber>043111-13</pasabm:LotNumber>
   <pasabm:LotSource>EBIZ_01</pasabm:LotSource>
   <pasabm:LotLocation>M1</pasabm:LotLocation>
   <pasabm:ExpirationDate/>
   <pasabm:TransactionSerialAssocVO>
      <pasabm:ItemSerialNumber>3173041321</pasabm:ItemSerialNumber>
      <pasabm:SerialType>USN-1</pasabm:SerialType>
      <pasabm:SerialIdentification>100-0711-1</pasabm:SerialIdentification>
      <pasabm:ParentSerialIdentification>918993-30413301-0413-23-1</pasabm:ParentSerialIdentification>
      <pasabm:ShippedItemFlag>0</pasabm:ShippedItemFlag>
     </pasabm:TransactionSerialAssocVO>
     <pasabm:TransactionSerialAssocVO>
         <pasabm:ItemSerialNumber>3173041322</pasabm:ItemSerialNumber>
     <pasabm:SerialType>USN-1</pasabm:SerialType>
     <pasabm:SerialIdentification/>
     <pasabm:ParentSerialIdentification>918993-30413301-0413-23-1</pasabm:ParentSerialIdentification>
     <pasabm:ShippedItemFlag>0</pasabm:ShippedItemFlag>
       </pasabm:TransactionSerialAssocVO>
       <pasabm:TransactionSerialAssocVO>
          <pasabm:ItemSerialNumber>3173041323</pasabm:ItemSerialNumber>
      <pasabm:SerialType>USN-1</pasabm:SerialType>
      <pasabm:SerialIdentification/>
      <pasabm:ParentSerialIdentification>918993-30413301-0413-23-1</pasabm:ParentSerialIdentification>
      <pasabm:ShippedItemFlag>0</pasabm:ShippedItemFlag>
    </pasabm:TransactionSerialAssocVO>
</pasabm:TransactionProductVO>
<pasabm:TransactionProductVO>
   <pasabm:ItemNumber>100-0711-1</pasabm:ItemNumber>
   <pasabm:ItemSource>EBIZ_01</pasabm:ItemSource>
   <pasabm:ItemUom>Ea</pasabm:ItemUom>
   <pasabm:LotNumber>043111-13</pasabm:LotNumber>
   <pasabm:LotSource>EBIZ_01</pasabm:LotSource>
   <pasabm:LotLocation>M1</pasabm:LotLocation>
   <pasabm:ExpirationDate/>
     <pasabm:TransactionSerialAssocVO>
         <pasabm:ItemSerialNumber>3173041322</pasabm:ItemSerialNumber>
     <pasabm:SerialType>USN-1</pasabm:SerialType>
     <pasabm:SerialIdentification/>
     <pasabm:ParentSerialIdentification>918993-30413301-0413-23-1</pasabm:ParentSerialIdentification>
     <pasabm:ShippedItemFlag>0</pasabm:ShippedItemFlag>
     </pasabm:TransactionSerialAssocVO>
     <pasabm:TransactionSerialAssocVO>
          <pasabm:ItemSerialNumber>3173041321</pasabm:ItemSerialNumber>
          <pasabm:SerialType>USN-1</pasabm:SerialType>
          <pasabm:SerialIdentification>100-0711-1</pasabm:SerialIdentification>
          <pasabm:ParentSerialIdentification>918993-30413301-0413-23-1</pasabm:ParentSerialIdentification>
          <pasabm:ShippedItemFlag>0</pasabm:ShippedItemFlag>
     </pasabm:TransactionSerialAssocVO>
      <pasabm:TransactionSerialAssocVO>
          <pasabm:ItemSerialNumber>3173041323</pasabm:ItemSerialNumber>
      <pasabm:SerialType>USN-1</pasabm:SerialType>
      <pasabm:SerialIdentification/>
      <pasabm:ParentSerialIdentification>918993-30413301-0413-23-1</pasabm:ParentSerialIdentification>
      <pasabm:ShippedItemFlag>0</pasabm:ShippedItemFlag>
      </pasabm:TransactionSerialAssocVO>
</pasabm:TransactionProductVO>
<pasabm:TransactionProductVO>
   <pasabm:ItemNumber>100-0711-1</pasabm:ItemNumber>
   <pasabm:ItemSource>EBIZ_01</pasabm:ItemSource>
   <pasabm:ItemUom>Ea</pasabm:ItemUom>
   <pasabm:LotNumber>043111-13</pasabm:LotNumber>
   <pasabm:LotSource>EBIZ_01</pasabm:LotSource>
   <pasabm:LotLocation>M1</pasabm:LotLocation>
   <pasabm:ExpirationDate/>
     <pasabm:TransactionSerialAssocVO>
         <pasabm:ItemSerialNumber>3173041323</pasabm:ItemSerialNumber>
     <pasabm:SerialType>USN-1</pasabm:SerialType>
     <pasabm:SerialIdentification/>
     <pasabm:ParentSerialIdentification>918993-30413301-0413-23-1</pasabm:ParentSerialIdentification>
     <pasabm:ShippedItemFlag>0</pasabm:ShippedItemFlag>
     </pasabm:TransactionSerialAssocVO>
     <pasabm:TransactionSerialAssocVO>
          <pasabm:ItemSerialNumber>3173041322</pasabm:ItemSerialNumber>
          <pasabm:SerialType>USN-1</pasabm:SerialType>
          <pasabm:SerialIdentification>100-0711-1</pasabm:SerialIdentification>
          <pasabm:ParentSerialIdentification>918993-30413301-0413-23-1</pasabm:ParentSerialIdentification>
          <pasabm:ShippedItemFlag>0</pasabm:ShippedItemFlag>
     </pasabm:TransactionSerialAssocVO>
      <pasabm:TransactionSerialAssocVO>
          <pasabm:ItemSerialNumber>3173041321</pasabm:ItemSerialNumber>
      <pasabm:SerialType>USN-1</pasabm:SerialType>
      <pasabm:SerialIdentification/>
      <pasabm:ParentSerialIdentification>918993-30413301-0413-23-1</pasabm:ParentSerialIdentification>
      <pasabm:ShippedItemFlag>0</pasabm:ShippedItemFlag>
      </pasabm:TransactionSerialAssocVO>
</pasabm:TransactionProductVO>
```

output i am expecting is:

```
<pasabm:TransactionProductVO>
   <pasabm:ItemNumber>100-0711-1</pasabm:ItemNumber>
   <pasabm:ItemSource>EBIZ_01</pasabm:ItemSource>
   <pasabm:ItemUom>Ea</pasabm:ItemUom>
   <pasabm:LotNumber>043111-13</pasabm:LotNumber>
   <pasabm:LotSource>EBIZ_01</pasabm:LotSource>
   <pasabm:LotLocation>M1</pasabm:LotLocation>
   <pasabm:ExpirationDate/>
   <pasabm:TransactionSerialAssocVO>
      <pasabm:ItemSerialNumber>3173041321</pasabm:ItemSerialNumber>
      <pasabm:SerialType>USN-1</pasabm:SerialType>
      <pasabm:SerialIdentification>100-0711-1</pasabm:SerialIdentification>
      <pasabm:ParentSerialIdentification>918993-30413301-0413-23-1</pasabm:ParentSerialIdentification>
      <pasabm:ShippedItemFlag>0</pasabm:ShippedItemFlag>
     </pasabm:TransactionSerialAssocVO>
     <pasabm:TransactionSerialAssocVO>
         <pasabm:ItemSerialNumber>3173041322</pasabm:ItemSerialNumber>
     <pasabm:SerialType>USN-1</pasabm:SerialType>
     <pasabm:SerialIdentification/>
     <pasabm:ParentSerialIdentification>918993-30413301-0413-23-1</pasabm:ParentSerialIdentification>
     <pasabm:ShippedItemFlag>0</pasabm:ShippedItemFlag>
       </pasabm:TransactionSerialAssocVO>
       <pasabm:TransactionSerialAssocVO>
          <pasabm:ItemSerialNumber>3173041323</pasabm:ItemSerialNumber>
      <pasabm:SerialType>USN-1</pasabm:SerialType>
      <pasabm:SerialIdentification/>
      <pasabm:ParentSerialIdentification>918993-30413301-0413-23-1</pasabm:ParentSerialIdentification>
      <pasabm:ShippedItemFlag>0</pasabm:ShippedItemFlag>
    </pasabm:TransactionSerialAssocVO>
</pasabm:TransactionProductVO>
```

Comment: XSLT is a transformation language for XML. Your input doesn't look like XML. Maybe another language is better suited for your purposes.

Comment: Assuming your input really is XML (perhaps the tags got lost because you didn't mark your data as code), the answer depends very much on whether you are able to use XSLT 2.0 or whether you are stuck with XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

With XSLT 1.0 use **[the Muenchian method for grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)**.

With XSLT 2.0 use **[`<xsl:for-each-group>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-for-each-group)**.