# using xslt to remove term if a property of it is a duplicate of another term

Tags: xslt, duplicates

I looked at [How to remove duplicate XML nodes using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355691/how-to-remove-duplicate-xml-nodes-using-xslt) and other related questions, but they all seem about removing duplicates if the whole node is a duplicate.  What I want to do is remove a node only if one properties within it matches a property within another node.

In my xml, I have 2 `termType`s; Nd and Pt.  Pts should be used. Where the system finds an Nd, the `termName` of it should not be used, instead, the name of the Pt referenced in `relation`  `termName` should be used instead.

But something has gone wrong and some Nds have the same name as the name of the Pts they should be referencing.  These terms are irrelevant and I need to delete them

I have:

```
<term>
<termId>1</termId>
<termUpdate>Add</termUpdate>
<termName>A</termName>
<termType>Nd</termType>
<relation>
  <relationType>USE</relationType>
  <termId>2</termId>
  <termName>A</termName>
</relation>
</term>

<term>
<termId>2</termId>
<termUpdate>Add</termUpdate>
<termName>A</termName>
<termType>Pt</termType>
</term>

<term>
<termId>3</termId>
<termUpdate>Add</termUpdate>
<termName>C</termName>
<termType>Nd</termType>
<relation>
  <relationType>USE</relationType>
  <termId>4</termId>
  <termName>D</termName>
</relation>
</term>

<term>
<termId>4</termId>
<termUpdate>Add</termUpdate>
<termName>D</termName>
<termType>Pt</termType>
</term>
```

Is it possible to use xslt (or some other method) to go through and see that, if the `<termName>` of an Nd `<term>` matches the `<termName>` of a Pt term in its `<relation>`, delete the whole term?  Terms referenced in `<relation>` are always Pt terms.

Output:

```
<term>
<termId>2</termId>
<termUpdate>Add</termUpdate>
<termName>A</termName>
<termType>Pt</termType>
</term>

<term>
<termId>3</termId>
<termUpdate>Add</termUpdate>
<termName>C</termName>
<termType>Nd</termType>
<relation>
  <relationType>USE</relationType>
  <termId>4</termId>
  <termName>D</termName>
</relation>
</term>

<term>
<termId>4</termId>
<termUpdate>Add</termUpdate>
<termName>D</termName>
<termType>Pt</termType>
</term>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution that is based on the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern -- the overriding of the identity rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kPtByName" match="term[termType='Pt']"
  use="termName"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="term[termType='Nd']">
  <xsl:if test="not(key('kPtByName', termName))">
   <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (wrapped into a top element to make it well-formed):

```
<terms>
    <term>
    <termId>1</termId>
    <termUpdate>Add</termUpdate>
    <termName>A</termName>
    <termType>Nd</termType>
    <relation>
      <relationType>USE</relationType>
      <termId>2</termId>
      <termName>A</termName>
    </relation>
    </term>

    <term>
    <termId>2</termId>
    <termUpdate>Add</termUpdate>
    <termName>A</termName>
    <termType>Pt</termType>
    </term>

    <term>
    <termId>3</termId>
    <termUpdate>Add</termUpdate>
    <termName>C</termName>
    <termType>Nd</termType>
    <relation>
      <relationType>USE</relationType>
      <termId>4</termId>
      <termName>D</termName>
    </relation>
    </term>

    <term>
    <termId>4</termId>
    <termUpdate>Add</termUpdate>
    <termName>D</termName>
    <termType>Pt</termType>
    </term>
</terms>
```

**produces the wanted, correct output**:

```
<terms>
   <term>
      <termId>2</termId>
      <termUpdate>Add</termUpdate>
      <termName>A</termName>
      <termType>Pt</termType>
   </term>
   <term>
      <termId>3</termId>
      <termUpdate>Add</termUpdate>
      <termName>C</termName>
      <termType>Nd</termType>
      <relation>
         <relationType>USE</relationType>
         <termId>4</termId>
         <termName>D</termName>
      </relation>
   </term>
   <term>
      <termId>4</termId>
      <termUpdate>Add</termUpdate>
      <termName>D</termName>
      <termType>Pt</termType>
   </term>
</terms>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **The [identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html) copies every node "as is"**.
2. **There is just one template that overrides the identity template**. It matches any `term` whose `termType` child has a value of `Nd`. This template only calls the `identity` template if there is no `term` with the same value of its `tername` child and whose `termType` child has a value of `Pt`. This test is performed using a conveniently defined `xsl:key`

Comment: Brilliant, that's perfect, apologies for the delay in getting back to you, my internet went down.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can also be solved by considering that we need to copy the nodes of type `Nd` only when the given condition is satisfied. We can then use `xsl:copy-of` to copy the wanted nodes and make use of the XSLT function `current()` to build a bit complex XPath.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:include href="identity.xsl"/>

 <xsl:template match="term[termType='Nd']" name="excludeNd">
     <xsl:copy-of select="self::node()
         [ not( ../term
                [ termId = current()/relation/termId ]
                    /termName = current()/termName )
         ]"/>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Where the template `exceludeNd` will include a term of type `Nd` in the output, **if and only if** its relation term **has not** the same name.

The included file `identity.xsl` is just an external stylesheet containing the well known **Identity Transform**.