# Is my XPath syntax correct?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

**This is my xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <check>
           <val>
              <Samsung>
                 <name value="galaxy" />
                 <name value="galaxy" />
                 <name value="galaxys" />
                 <id value="123" />
                 <id value="123" />
                 <name2 value="galaxy" />
             </Samsung>

             <htc>
                 <name value="galaxy" />
                 <name value="galaxy" />
                 <name value="galaxys" />
                 <id value="123" />
                 <id value="123" />
                 <name2 value="galaxy" />
    </htc>
</val>
```

**My Xpath expression is:**

```
XPathExpression expr = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath()
                .compile("//Samsung/name/@value");
```

In the above xml  `<name value="galaxy" />` has copies , so am trying to delete the duplicates. But in my code am getting the node where value="galaxys".. which I shouldn't be deleting. Also What should be the correct XPath syntax so I could use it to delete duplicates, where it should match both element and attribute value(for eg: ) **in the entire xml?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355691/how-to-remove-duplicate-xml-nodes-using-xslt

Comment: It's not working. Plus in my xml I need to match both element name and attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

Expression "//Samsung/name/@value" returns value attribute of all 'name' nodes under 'Samsung' nodes so it should return 'galaxys'

if you want to put criteria to just returns node with value='galaxy' you can use this expression 
//Samsung/name[@value='galaxy']/

Answer (score 0):

Try the below with `xml` code:

```
           <val>
              <Samsung>
                 <name value="galaxy" />
                 <name value="galaxy" />
                 <name value="galaxys" />
                 <id value="123" />
                 <id value="123" />
                 <name2 value="galaxy" />
             </Samsung>

             <htc>
                 <name value="galaxy" />
                 <name value="galaxy" />
                 <name value="galaxys" />
                 <id value="123" />
                 <id value="123" />
                 <name2 value="galaxy" />
    </htc>
</val>
```

***XPATH:***

```
//val/Samsung/child::*[@value = "galaxy"]
```

***Output:***

[image: xpath]

Comment: I used similar aprroach recursively.. Can you look at this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167059/small-issue-with-deleting-duplicates-in-xml-using-java