# Batch script to delete duplicate lines but wanted to ignore/skip some lines

Tags: windows, batch-file, duplicates, file-processing

Is it also possible to ignore some duplicate lines while removing other duplicates from an xml file, example: if my abx.xml is 
CODE:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "file=%~1"
set "line=%file%.line"
set "deduped=%file%.deduped"
::Define a variable containing a linefeed character
set LF=^


::The 2 blank lines above are critical, do not remove
>"%deduped%" (
  for /f usebackq^ eol^=^%LF%%LF%^ delims^= %%A in ("%file%") do (
    set "ln=%%A"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    >"%line%" (echo !ln:\=\\!)
    >nul findstr /xlg:"%line%" "%deduped%" || (echo !ln!)
    endlocal
  )
)
>nul move /y "%deduped%" "%file%"
2>nul del "%line%"
```

Only **BATCH SCRIPT** PLEASE.

```
<bookstores>
   <book id="parent">
      <name="it1"/>
      <name="it1"/>
      <name="it2"/>
   </book>
   <book id="child">
      <name="it1"/>
      <name="it1"/>
      <name="it2"/>
      <name="it3"/>
   </book>     
</bookstores>
```

Output should be:

```
<bookstores>
   <book id="parent">
      <name="it1"/>
      <name="it2"/>
   </book>
   <book id="child">
      <name="it3"/>
   </book>     
</bookstores>
```

But the output i am getting is:
**NOTE:** `</book>` tag is removed.

```
<bookstores>
   <book id="parent">
      <name="it1"/>
      <name="it2"/>
   </book>
   <book id="child">
      <name="it3"/>

</bookstores>
```

I have searched couple of simillar requests but most of them are deleting all duplicate lines,but not sure how to ignore some duplicate lines:

[Batch to remove duplicate rows from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689689/batch-to-remove-duplicate-rows-from-text-file/17859683#17859683)

Comment: You are trying to treat XML as a plain text file. Which it is, and it isn't. XML is a structure, and the link you posted is for a non-structured file. Sometimes you have to use the right tool for the job. Something like [`XSLT`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355691/how-to-remove-duplicate-xml-nodes-using-xslt) would be far more appropriate for this.

Comment: Post your code so that we don't have to re-write it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689689/batch-to-remove-duplicate-rows-from-text-file/17859683#17859683 the given link is having the code.

Comment: Please add code to your question. It is not readable in the comment box.

Comment: code added to the question.

Comment: @Gray can you give a sample XSLT code for the following `<bookstore>` example.

Comment: @phani No disrespect intended, but sorry, I don't want to do that, no. My suggestion is to take a look at the link I gave (maybe you didn't notice it was a link, I didn't make it very clear) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355691/how-to-remove-duplicate-xml-nodes-using-xslt If you decide to go with something like that, and can't figure it out, post a new question to SO with what you tried, but with the XSLT tag. I'm sure you will get prompt help, you just have to make the effort.

Comment: Thanks @Gary, looks like the approach that you suggested me is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you, if you put *lines always to print* in the `%dict%` file:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "file=file"
SET "new=new"
SET "dict=dictionary"

(FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n "^" "%file%"') DO (
    SET "nr=%%a"
    SET "line=%%b"
    SET "this="
    FINDSTR /l "!line!" "%dict%" >NUL 2>&1&& ECHO(!line! || (
        FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%x IN ('set "$" 2^>nul') DO IF !line!==%%y SET "this=1"
        IF "!this!"=="" (
            ECHO(!line!
            SET "$!nr!=!line!"
        )
    )
))>"%new%"
TYPE "%new%"
```

..shell session:

```
    >type file
    <bookstores>
       <book id="parent">
          <name="it1"/>
          <name="it1"/>
          <name="it2"/>
       </book>
       <book id="child">
          <name="it1"/>
          <name="it1"/>
          <name="it2"/>
          <name="it3"/>
       </book>
    </bookstores>

    >type dictionary
    </book>

    >script.bat
    <bookstores>
       <book id="parent">
          <name="it1"/>
          <name="it2"/>
       </book>
       <book id="child">
          <name="it3"/>
       </book>
    </bookstores>
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, Since this is an xml file, i have decided to use XSLT to process the xml file. Appreciate your help.